# Face extrusion only working in one direction?

Tags: extrude

I need to get a solid object by extruding the face **down the Z-axis** their normals.

1. Select object in object mode
2. Hit Tab to edit mode
3. Hit a
4. Hit e

However, extrude only produces a solid mesh **up** the Z axis
[image: pic]
but only a hollow thing toward my wanted direction (down Z axis)?
[image: pic]

[image]

Comment: For a start you've got almost 96000 overlapping vertices in that mesh, presumably produced by Zbrush! In edit mode, select all and then M > Merge by Distance to clean up the mesh. Then do your extruding, select all again and ALT -N > Flip Normals to ensure they're pointing outwards.

Comment: @JohnEason: how do you know the number of overlapping vertices!?

Comment: Calculated by looking at the number of verts in the bottom right of the status bar before (96384)  and after (497) merging them and doing a rough subtraction!